# WPF Disabled DatagridRow and ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

I have a datagrid binded to a collection of custom objects.

This datagrid allows the user to access a context menu when he right clicks a row.  I do this through TextBlock styling:

```
<Style x:Key="DatagridTextblockStyle"
    TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="First action" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It also displays rows which might be disabled if the custom object's "IsActive" bool property is false.

I do this through the DataGrid.RowStyle:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCustomObjects}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                            Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

This works fine. 
The problem however is that when a row is disabled, the context menu is not available anymore.

I can't find a way around that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey @mm8, thanks for taking the time out of your day to wite a comment and help me. This actually did the trick, I feel bad I didn't think about it -_-. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled` attached property to `true` in the `ElementStyle`:

```
<Style x:Key="DatagridTextblockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="First action" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hey @mm8, thanks for taking the time out of your day to wite a comment and help me. This actually did the trick, I feel bad I didn't think about it -_-. Thanks man.

Comment: @Louitbol: There is nothing to feel bad for here. Please keep asking questions!